# Loading Indicator in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, alamofire

How can display a loading indicator in an view controller.

I am using Alamofire in  viewDidLoad() ....

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, formURL, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, jsonResult, error) in


            }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that but if you call the Alamofire in view controller you can add those properties to the class:

```
var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
```

And add two helpers, you should customise is to whatever fit right in your app:

```
func showActivityIndicator() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadingView = UIView()
        self.loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        self.loadingView.center = self.view.center
        self.loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#444444")
        self.loadingView.alpha = 0.7
        self.loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
        self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0)
        self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x:self.loadingView.bounds.size.width / 2, y:self.loadingView.bounds.size.height / 2)

        self.loadingView.addSubview(self.spinner)
        self.view.addSubview(self.loadingView)
        self.spinner.startAnimating()
    }
}

func hideActivityIndicator() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self.loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

And call it when you need, for example:

```
showActivityIndicator()
Alamofire.request(.GET, formURL, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, jsonResult, error) in
             self.hideActivityIndicator()

            }
```

Comment: @Greg very good answer! `UIColor(rgba: "#444444")` didn't work for me though, had to use something like `UIColor(red: 0.26, green: 0.26, blue: 0.26, alpha: 0.7)`

Comment: @fagiani UIColor(rgba: "#444444") is my own custom extension  on UIColor class.

Comment: you need this for the UIColor: https://gist.github.com/yannickl/16f0ed38f0698d9a8ae7